# Android Studio very slow lint

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.3

I do not remember the exact version, but about from 3.2, the lint processing of Android studio has become dreadful.

ctrl + b won't work for about 5min after putting the code, and red lines which are supposed to indicate unwritten methods or wrong referencing is completely broken.

I never had such issue on the previous versions, and I don't know what to do with this. I looked through stackoverflow with the tag android-studio, but no one seems to have the same issue, or I'm selecting the wrong keyword for this.

But, all three of my colleagues are having the same issue from a certain version of Android studio.

Is this an issue with vmOption? Please help.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: @Mahdi-Malv In my case, a single plugin called "Prettify" was the problem. Removing the plugin resolved the issue, not a bug of Android Studio. I suggest on removing deprecated (or not maintained) plugins from your setting.

Comment: Started for me recently as well. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Sermillion As I stated at the comment above, check out your plugins. Thats what the problem was for me.